# Как скрыть сроллбар CSS?

Tags: css, scrollbar

Как скрыть сроллбар или сделать его невидимым?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```